# How to fix JavaScript function that prevents dropdown list from working

Tags: javascript, dropdown, intl

My complete JavaScript code is https://jsfiddle.net/JSstarter/0t98gbg3/. 
Dropdown list worked, but after I add setFormat function, the dropdown list stops working and it doesn't show the list of locales. 
Can someone please help me how to fix the JavaScript part to get the dropdown list  and also the setFormat function to work?

```
<p id="demo">Please select a locale to show data.</p>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Locales</button>
<div id="locale" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#enUS" onclick="setFormat('en-US')">en-US</a>
<a href="#koKR" onclick="setFormat('ko-KR')">ko-KR</a>
<a href="#zhCN" onclick="setFormat('zh-Hans-CN')">zh-Hans-CN</a>
<a href="#jaJP" onclick="setFormat('ja-JP')">ja-JP</a>
<a href="#deDE" onclick="setFormat('de-DE')">de-DE</a>
<a href="#ruRU" onclick="setFormat('ru-RU')">ru-RU</a>
<a href="#arSA" onclick="setFormat('ar-SA')">ar-SA</a>
</div>
</div>
<script>

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("locale").classList.toggle("show");
}

setFormat(locale) {
var date = new Date(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-   US').format(date);
document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1234.56);
};

</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword in front of `setFormat`

Answer (score 1):

Super easy fix. You are missing the word 'function' before setFormat(locale). Also I noticed you are passing the variable 'locale' but you don't actually use it in the function. I assume you might need that later on but just pointing it out.

```
<script>

function setFormat(locale) {
    var date = new Date(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
    document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
    document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1234.56);
};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("locale").classList.toggle("show");
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors. `getElementByID` is spelled `getElementById` and you forgot function in front of `setFormat`. You can see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5d8Lxkg/) for a demo.

The end result looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("locale").classList.toggle("show");
}

function setFormat(locale) {
   var date = new Date(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1234.56);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
<p id="demo">Please select a locale to show data.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Locales</button>
  <div id="locale" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#enUS" onclick="setFormat('en-US')">en-US</a>
    <a href="#koKR" onclick="setFormat('ko-KR')">ko-KR</a>
    <a href="#zhCN" onclick="setFormat('zh-Hans-CN')">zh-Hans-CN</a>
    <a href="#jaJP" onclick="setFormat('ja-JP')">ja-JP</a>
    <a href="#deDE" onclick="setFormat('de-DE')">de-DE</a>
    <a href="#ruRU" onclick="setFormat('ru-RU')">ru-RU</a>
    <a href="#arSA" onclick="setFormat('ar-SA')">ar-SA</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setFormat(locale) {
var date = new Date(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
 document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1234.56);
};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("locale").classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>


<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
```